# Could not run SSIS package using agent job

Tags: sql-server, ssis, database-administration, ssis-2012, sql-agent-job

[image]I could not run a SSIS package using SQL Server Agent Job. I have given the admin right to the folder where the package is located. When i execute the SSIS package it runs fine all the times but SQL Server agent could not complete the process.
I get the following error :

> Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. Started:  1:46:11 AM 
>   Finished: 1:46:45 AM  Elapsed:  33.953 seconds.  The package execution
>   failed.  The step failed.

whenever i run the job manually.
Please help

[image]

Comment: add the error in the second row of log file summary please

Comment: Even if `NT service\SQLSERVERAGENT` has access to the folder where the package is located I think it's a better idea to deploy SSIS packages to SSISDB than to put them on a system folder.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vercelli
I have created the SSIDB catalogue and deploy, but even after that same error. Will there be any authorization issue?

Comment: @AshishMandal OK, but are you executing the SSISDB stored package in the job? Please post step definition.

Comment: Yes
i have created a ssis package then i opened SSMS, Management-integration services catalogue-right click then "create catalogue-entered password then ok
right click on SSISDB then create folder
right click on project and then depoy- provided the location - deployment successful.

Then i went to JOBs, right click - new job- name of the job in general tab
in step- new step-entered the step name 
selected SSIS in type field
then in package - package source selected SSIS Catalog
the provided the server name 
then entered the package location
then clicked ok

Comment: @AshishMandal that's sounds ok to me. Error is the same? could you post all the errors? (edit your question)

Comment: @AshishMandal it's weird that the job takes almost 34 seconds to fail. It looks like it's doing something and encounters an error. It doesn't seem an authoritation error.

Comment: SQL Agent error is Message
Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. Started:  1:46:11 AM  Finished: 1:46:45 AM  Elapsed:  33.953 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

Comment: When i start the job manually from sql agent job it gives me the error :
Execution of job "jobname" failed see the history for details

Comment: And the best part is when i execute the ssis package manually it works fine all the times

Comment: @AshishMandal export the log and post it. It might be many things, you may have a connection to a DB using windows auth (that will be different on the job).

Comment: @vercelli please find the log attached

Comment: Sorry for the delay, i have attached it now

Comment: @AshishMandal It clearly says that "There is already an object named 'DF__PRE_SCREE__CREAT__1B5E0D89' in the database"...

Comment: Sorry for this, the last one was old log file, i have uploaded the log file for the job in question.

Comment: You should take a look at the SSISDB reports as the log is telling you. Export that report and post it here (but I'm asuming the error might be the same)

Comment: Just in case you havent't tried yet: did you try to change the account, under which the agent is running, to yout account? Should be somewhere in the config wizard... or - might be a bit easier - call the package in the job with your credentials instead of Service\SQLSERVERAGENT? If one of these solutions work, it IS an authorization problem.

Comment: let me do that.

Comment: If it isn't getting to actually processing any data, then it's failing on pre-validation checks. This could be either in your data sources or tasks in your package. What I do in these situations is to disable all tasks but leave the connections, see if it runs. If it does, then start enabling your tasks one at a time. If it doesn't, then you know it's a permissions issue with one of your connections.